# React "Encountered an invalid child" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using react to render a table that acts similar to a spreadsheet.  Each cell has an input field, and you can fill each cell throughout a row.  However, I only want there to be one row of inputs empty at all times.  I'm using the following code to render the `<tbody>`

```
var existing_rows_length = this.state.existing_rows.length
  , new_index = existing_rows_length + this.state.new_rows.length - 1

var existing_rows = this.state.existing_rows.map(function(row, i) {
  return (
    <TableRow data={row} key={"row-" + i} index={i} />
  )
})

var new_rows = this.state.new_line_items.map(function(row, i) {
  return (
    <TableRow data={li} key={"row-" + i + existing_row_length} index={i + existing_row_length} unsaved={true} />
  )
})

return (
  <tbody>
    {existing_rows}
    {new_line_items}
    <TableRow data={{}} index={new_index} unsaved={true} />
  </tbody>
)
```

Then, on every input of a field, it serializes the inputs, and sets them to "new_rows"

```
var new_rows = $(this.getDOMNode())
  .find('[data-unsaved][data-has-changed]')
  .map(function(i, el) { return $(el).find('input') })
  .map(function(i, inputs) {
    return _.reduce(inputs, function(memo, input) {
      var $input = $(input)
        , attrName = $input.attr('name').match(/\[([^\[]*)\]$/)[1]
      memo[attrName] = $input.val()
      return memo
      }, {})
  })

this.setState({ // This is line 17, in the function ensureNewRow, of table_body.js
  existing_rows: this.state.existing_rows
, new_rows: new_rows
})
```

My logic being that once you start to fill out inputs in a new row, then it will save that in state.new_rows and render out another blank row beneath it.  However, instead it stops rendering and gives me the following error:

```
[Warning] Child objects should have non-numeric keys so ordering is preserved. Check the render method of LineItemList. See http://fb.me/react-warning-keys for more information. (851543_741761425909553_1789649762_n.js, line 9663)
[Error] Error: Invariant Violation: traverseAllChildren(...): Encountered an invalid child; DOM elements are not valid children of React components.
  perform (851543_741761425909553_1789649762_n.js, line 15428)
  batchedUpdates (851543_741761425909553_1789649762_n.js, line 8681)
  enqueueUpdate (851543_741761425909553_1789649762_n.js, line 13744)
  replaceState (851543_741761425909553_1789649762_n.js, line 6211)
  setState (851543_741761425909553_1789649762_n.js, line 6183)
  ensureNewRow (table_body.js, line 17)
  (anonymous function) ([native code], line 0)
  dispatch (jquery.js, line 4642)
  handle (jquery.js, line 4310)
```

Following the link actually takes me here: "http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children" where it says to prepend the keys with strings (which I have done - I tried prefixing them with the same prefix, and tried with different prefixes).

Sorry the code isn't too pretty, I've been stuck on this issue for days!  If anyone can at least point me in the right direction, or let me know what may be causing the issue, that would be very helpful!  Or, if I'm violating some React principle, let me know what it is so I can fix it (this is my first time using React after all)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was coming from accidentally saving a query object into the state.  This caused the variables to flip in the map function, setting the key to [object Object] and leaving `<TableRow>` to render given only an integer.  I just called `.toArray()` at the end of the `new_rows` assignment chain and it worked!